# Using nokogiri xpath to access nested elements within an xmlns

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm new to nokogiri and am having trouble using xpath to access nested elements of an xml document with a specific xmlns.

Given the following code

```
#!/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.8">
    <profiles>
      <profile name="full">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
                <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:/Paulstestjndi" pool-name="pauls_ds" enabled="false">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@testhost1:80001paulstestinstance|jdbc:oracle:thin:@testhost2:80001paulstestinstance</connection-url>
                    </datasource>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</domain>
XML

datasources = doc.xpath('//datasources:datasource', 'datasources' => "urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2")
datasources.each do |datasource|
  conn_url = datasource.xpath("connection-url")
  puts "CLASS = #{conn_url.class}"
  puts "No of Entries = #{conn_url.length}"
end
```

I am able to retrieve datasources using xpath but am unable to use xpath to access 'connection-url' for each datasource.

I have tried several xpath calls to achieve this the following are examples

```
conn_url = datasource.xpath("connection-url")
conn_url = datasource.xpath("//connection-url")
conn_url = datasource.xpath("//datasources:datasource/connection-url", 'datasources'=>"urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2")
```

But each seems to return an empty set of results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a namespacing issue:

```
datasource.xpath(
  'subsystem:connection-url',
  'subsystem' => 'urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2')
#⇒ [#<... name="connection-url" namespace=...
```